# Create a VPN Reflector to connect from laptop to home network via server in cloud

Tags: windows-7, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access

Is is possible to use a Windows Server 2008 r2 Datacenter edition server in the cloud to route a VPN connection from my laptop via the server so that I can connect to my computers at home without opening any ports on my homes firewall.

I would like to use the builtin windows tools on windows server(network access and routing) and the windows VPN client.

The ideal solution would haave a diagram like this:

Laptop ==========> Server <================ Home Server (Bridge both VPN Connections together)

Where ====== is a VPN connection. Any help would be appreciated.